# postgresql do not return values on specific numeric criterias

Tags: sql, postgresql, real-datatype

I have a postgresql database which look like the following :

```
+---------------+---------------- ------+------------ ---+
|  id (bigint)  |  name (varying(255))  |  price (real)  |
+---------------+---------------- ------+------------ ---+
|       1       |          name 1       |        0.33    |
+---------------+---------------- ------+------------ ---+
|       1       |          name 2       |        1.33    |
+---------------+---------------- ------+------------ ---+
|       1       |          name 3       |        1       |
+---------------+---------------- ------+------------ ---+
```

And then the results of my queries :

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE price = 1    -- OK (one row returned)
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE price = 1.0  -- OK (one row returned)
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE price = 1.33 -- FAIL (no row returned)
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE price = 0.33 -- FAIL (no row returned)
```

When the value can't be cast to an non-floating value no lines are returned by postgresql.

I can't figure out why. Have you the same problem ? How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution I see is to use explicit cast to `real` datatype:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE price = 0.33::real;
 id |  name  | price 
----+--------+-------
  1 | name 1 |  0.33

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE price = 1.33::real;
 id |  name  | price 
----+--------+-------
  1 | name 2 |  1.33
```

According to [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#AEN1466):

> A numeric constant that contains neither a decimal point nor an
>   exponent is initially presumed to be type integer if its value fits in
>   type integer (32 bits); otherwise it is presumed to be type bigint if
>   its value fits in type bigint (64 bits); otherwise it is taken to be
>   type numeric. Constants that contain decimal points and/or exponents
>   are always initially presumed to be type **numeric**.

Note that:

```
SELECT 1.33::numeric = 1.33::real;
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you for this interesting and useful answer :)